# Calculate the length of time

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, datetime

I have a `data` as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(ymdhms=c(20230301000000,20230301000010,20230301000020,20230301000030,20230301000040,
                          20230301000050,20230301000100,20230301000110,20230301000120,20230301000130,
                          20230301000140,20230301000150,20230301000200,20230301000210,20230301000220),
                 switch=c(40,41,42,43,0,0,0,51,52,53,54,0,0,48,47))
```

`ymdhms` means year, month, day, hour, minute and second. For example, `20230301000000` menas 00:00:00, March 1st, 2023.
If `switch` is bigger than 0, that means the switch is on. If `switch` is 0, that means the switch is off. `switch`always has nonnegative values.

I want to calculate the duration of the time when switch is on and when switch is off.
Every rows of `data` has 10 seconds time intervals. So for the switch on case, the duration times are 30seconds, 30 seconds, and 10 seconds. For the switch off case, the duration times are 20 seconds and 10 seconds. So, my expected output is like this:

```
on_off<-data.frame(on=c(30,30,10),off=c(20,10,NA))
```

I made extra columns to calculate `on_off` like below.

```
data$dt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(formatC(data$ymdhms, format='f'), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))

data$switchStatus_A <- ifelse(data$switch > 0, 1, 0) #If switch > 0, switch is on and we indicate it as 1. 
                                                    # Otherwise, if switch is 0, switch is off and we indicate it as 0.
```

I don't know how to do next to get `on_off`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *data.table::rleid*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, grp := paste0(fifelse(switch > 0, "on_", "off_"), rleid(switch > 0))
            ][, .(duration = .N * 10), by = grp]
#      grp duration
# 1:  on_1       40
# 2: off_2       30
# 3:  on_3       40
# 4: off_4       20
# 5:  on_5       20
```